# Create one continuous polygon from many polygons with holes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, merge, holes

How can I create one single continuous polygon from many polygon and the gaps will be preserved? So whole polygon will be connect into one big single polygon.

[image: This layer I would like to connect into single continuous polygon]

Using the dissolve tool will not connect every polygon to single continuous polygon. Image below is output which I would like.

[image: I would like to get something like that]

Comment: Are you looking to fill in the "Whitespace" in your dataset? Using your first picture, just have a green polygon within the boundary?

Comment: What you've drawn isn't a valid polygon. There is little demand for generation of topologically corrupt features.

Comment: Do you really need to create a spatially continuous polygon, or considering it as one multipolygon feature made of various polygons is ok ?

Comment: What is your criterion for connecting the polygons? Because it certainly isn't the closest point, from what you have drawn.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the Dissolve tool. It will add all polygons to a single one while maintaining the gaps.

[image]

Comment: Yes I tried Dissolve tool but this does not connect every polygon to one continous polygon.